# How make git use (hard) links for checked out duplicate files

Tags: git, filesystems

My little programm has a lot of XML files in several directories. 
From time to time some of the XML files become obsolete and some have to be added. In that case we create a new directory, essentially copy the files and delete some and add some. For several reasons I do not have control over the format the data is stored.

- root

  - v1

    - 1.xml
    - 2.xml
    - many more
  - v2

    - a slightly changed set of xml files

These files are then stored in a git. 
The git repo itself is pretty small, because the data is easy to compress.
However is there a way make git using hard links for duplicate files in the checked out state? The checkout is pretty slow because it has to crate a lot of small files.
Maybe some file system in combination with git?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to *not* copy/duplicate those xml files, and simply add/update their content.

You can make a tag (git tag -m "v1" V1) before modifying those files, then modify/add/remove them, `git add .` and `git commit`, to record the new state of your XML files.